# How to show jquery dialog with radio buttons when checkbox is checked and post value in textbox

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have 41 checkboxes like this

**HTML**

```
<input id="1" type="checkbox" onclick="updatebox()" />
<input id="2" type="checkbox" onclick="updatebox()" />
<input id="3" type="checkbox" onclick="updatebox()" />
<input id="4" type="checkbox" onclick="updatebox()" />
```

**Javascript**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function updatebox()
{
    var textbox = document.getElementById("list");
    var values = [];
 if(document.getElementById('1').checked) {values.push("1");}
 if(document.getElementById('2').checked) {values.push("2");}
 if(document.getElementById('3').checked) {values.push("3");}
 if(document.getElementById('4').checked) {values.push("4");}

    textbox.value = values.join(", ");

}
</script>
```

When checkbox is checked the value is posted in textbox,
now what i want is when the user clicks the checkbox the jquery dialog popups and the user will have two radio buttons with Male or Female options along with ok button so when the user will click on ok the value should be posted on textbox depending on selection M for male F for female along with number like 1M or 1F, 2M or 2F and so on.

P.S user can select multiple checkboxes.

Thanks You!

Comment: What will be the result when select multiple check boxes? Will the code have generate a list with one M or F like 1M,3M,7M or 1F,3F,7F? Or will there be multiple gender choices for each number?

Comment: it will be like 1M,2F,3M 12M and so on depending on gender choices

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is something that does what you want. HTML:

```
<body>
  <form id="form">
    <input id="1" type="checkbox" /> 1
    <input id="2" type="checkbox" /> 2
    <input id="3" type="checkbox" /> 3
    <input id="4" type="checkbox" /> 4
    ...
    <input id="10" type="checkbox" /> 10
    ...
    <input id="41" type="checkbox" /> 41
    <input id="list" />
  </form>
  <div id="prompt" style="display:none;" title="Gender">
    <form>
      <input type="radio" name="gender" id="radio" value="male" />
      <label for="radio">Male</label>
      <input type="radio" name="gender" id="radio2" value="female" />
      <label for="radio2">Female</label>
    </form>
  </div>
</body>
```

The JavaScript:

```
$(function() {
   var form = document.getElementById("form");
   var textbox = document.getElementById("list");
   var $prompt = $("#prompt");

   // We record what is currently checked, and the user's answers in this `pairs` object. 
   var pairs = [];

   // Listen to `change` events.
   $("input[type='checkbox']", form).on('change', function (ev) {
     var check = ev.target;

     if (check.checked) {
       // Checked, so prompt and record.
       $prompt.dialog({
         modal: true,
         buttons: {
          "Ok": function() {
             var gender = $prompt.find("input[name='gender']:checked")[0];
             var letter = {"male":"M", "female":"F"}[gender.value];

             pairs[check.id] = '' + check.id + letter;
             $( this ).dialog( "close" );
             refresh();
           }
         }
       });
     }
     else {
       // Unchecked, so forget it.
       delete pairs[check.id];
       refresh();
     }

     function refresh() {
       // Generate what we must now display in the textbox and refresh it.

       // We walk the list.
       var keys = Object.keys(pairs);
       var values = [];
       for (var i = 0, key; (key = keys[i]); ++i) {
         values.push(pairs[key]);
       }
       textbox.value = values.join(", ");
     }
   }); 
});
```

Here is a [jsbin](http://jsbin.com/zavitixama/1/edit?html,js,output) with the code above.

Salient points:

1. This code adds the event handlers using JavaScript rather than use `onclick` in the HTML. It is not recommended to associated handlers directly in the HTML.
2. It listens to the `change` event rather than `click`. Some clicks can sometimes not result in a change to an input element.
3. It uses `$.dialog` to prompt the user for M, F.
4. The `refresh` function is what recomputes the text field.
5. It keeps a record of what is currently checked rather than requery for all the check boxes when one of them changes.

Comment: Thanks for the answer but i want to show dialog like this [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/hasnain209/u895qtdm/3/) and then post the result in textbox.
Thanks!

Comment: It was not clear to me that your issue was how to create the dialog box. I've updated my answer.

Answer (score 1):

```
function updatebox()
{
    var textbox = document.getElementById("list");
    var values = [];
    for (var i = 1; i <= 41; ++i) {
        var id = '' + i;
        if (document.getElementById(id).checked) {
            var gender = prompt('Male (M) or female (F)?');
            values.push(gender + id);
        }
    }

    textbox.value = values.join(", ");
}
```

A few things to note:

- I got rid of all that code repetition by simply using a `for` loop from 1 to 41.
- I also fixed the strange indentation you had there.
- You may want to use a method of getting user input other than `prompt`, but it'll work the same way.
- (If you're going to keep using `prompt`, you might also want to add input validation as well to make sure the user didn't input something other than `M` or `F`.)

Comment: The problem is when the user deselects the checkbox the dialog still appears and also when the user checks the checkbox the dialog appears unnecessarily.